# How to bind imageurl to its imageId stored in database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have uploaded  a image and store it into a folder in asp.net and stored its description in database my Photo table contains following column

```
ProductPhoto
Column Name Data Type   Constraint
PhotoID     Int         Primary key,auto increment
PhotoName   Varchar(100)    
ExtName     Varchar(100)    
PhotoType   Varchar(100)    
PhotoSize   Int 
ProductID   Int         Foreign key with product info
```

and stored image in folder named "upload"

And In a gridview in which i have bound all the columns to the database i have taken a image in a item template and and bind its imageurl using this code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gridview" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="3" Height="238px"  BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellSpacing="2">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Photo ID" DataField="PhotoID" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Photo Name" DataField="PhotoName" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Extention Name" DataField="ExtName" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Photo Type" DataField="PhotoType" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Photo Size" DataField="PhotoSize" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Product ID" DataField="ProductID" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Image">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="productimg"  Height="108px"  ImageUrl="~/upload/" Width="98px" runat="server"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete Record">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are You Sure To Delete The Record?')" Text="Delete This Record" CommandName="del" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PhotoID") %>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit  Record">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="update"  CommandName="upd" Text="Edit this Record" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PhotoID") %>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
     <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
     <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
     <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
     <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
     <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
     <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
     <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
     <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

and to upload the image i have used this code

protected void Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

```
    if (photoupload.HasFile)
    {
        ProductPhoto prdctphoto = new ProductPhoto();
        prdctphoto.PhotoName = photoupload.FileName;
        prdctphoto.PhotoSize = photoupload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        prdctphoto.PhotoType = photoupload.PostedFile.ContentType;
        prdctphoto.ExtName = prdctphoto.PhotoName.Substring(prdctphoto.PhotoName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        prdctphoto.ProductID = int.Parse(ddlproductname.SelectedValue);
        //Response.Write(data.ExtName);
        int ans = new InsertAction().InsertData(prdctphoto);
        if (ans != 0)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/upload/") + ans.ToString() + "." + prdctphoto.ExtName;
            photoupload.SaveAs(path);
            lblmsg.Text=" File is Uploaded ";
        }

        else
        {
            lblmsg.Text="Please check all the fields";
        }

    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

}

Comment: What's the url created by the server for the image?

Comment: i dont know about that

Comment: If you're using Chrome, right click on the broken image and then "Copy image URL".

Comment: thanks sir , image url is http://localhost:1033/upload/localhost:1033/upload/PhotoName.ExtName

Comment: As you can see from your link, the problem is that the fields "PhotoName" and "ExtName" aren't bound to your data. Can you post your page to give us the possibility to understand? :)

Comment: u mean the page Product.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try with the below code snippet?

```
ImageUrl='<%# "~/upload/" +Eval("PhotoName").ToString().Trim()+"." + Eval("ExtName").ToString().Trim()  %>'
```

OR

```
ImageUrl='<%#  Request.Url.Scheme + System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Host + (Request.Url.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + Request.Url.Port) + "/upload/" +Eval("PhotoName")+"." + Eval("ExtName")  %>'
```

Let me know if it is not working.

Comment: can you please provide generated URL and actual URL where the image is exists?

Comment: genrated url is simply the page name http://localhost:1033/admin/ProductPhoto.aspx and image exists in the folder "~/upload/"

Comment: Folder is exists in root directory or in inside admin directory?

Comment: In addition also replace photoname and ExtName with below URL and check that image is exists or not. http://localhost:1033/upload/PhotoName.ExtName

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34151/discussion-between-jayesh-goyani-and-vjain)

Answer (score 1):

Image url will

```
ImageUrl= '<%#"~/upload/" + Eval("PhotoID").ToString().Trim() + "." + Eval("ExtName").ToString().Trim()  %>'
```

bcoz i have save the image path as

```
 int ans = new InsertAction().InsertData(prdctphoto);
        if (ans != 0)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/upload/") + ans.ToString() + "." + prdctphoto.ExtName;
}
```

where in ans ProductID is stored and therfore the obtained imageurl will be like this

```
http://localhost:1033/upload/7.jpg
```

where 7 is PhotoID